# Pigeonhole Principle application for number of hair

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

As a beginner, I was reading Pigeonhole Principle from Wikipedia. The statement of PHP as it stated was very clear to me.

> The pigeonhole principle states that if n items are put into m containers, with n > m, then at least one container must contain more than one item.

This is very clear to me but one of the applications as stated by wikipedia went just over my head and I could not understand how this is related with PHP. The example from Wikipedia goes as follows

> For example, given that the population of London is greater than the maximum number of hairs that can be present on a human's head, then the pigeonhole principle requires that there must be at least two people in London who have the same number of hairs on their heads.

Now can anyone explain a beginner how is this an application of PHP?

Comment: Make containers big enough to fit a reasonable number of Londoners, and label them with $0, 1, 2, \ldots, m$, where $m$ is the maximum number of hairs on a human being. Now invite all (say $n$) Londoners, and as they come, count the number of hairs for each person and send that person to the corresponding container. Once all $n$ Londoners are in, per PHP, and knowing that $n>m+1$ you will have at least two Londoners in one container, and those two must have the same number of hairs. Note that this is only a thought experiment and that conducting it in real life would be cruel.

Comment: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/the-worlds-simplest-theorem-shows-that-8-000-people-globally-have-the-same-number-of-hairs-on-their-head/#:~:text=Depending%20on%20hair%20color%2C%20the,more%20than%20a%20million%20hairs. A fun article about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clean up the unanswered line:

The number of hairs a person has is a natural number. The number of people from london is also a natural number. Since the later is greater than the former, pigeonhole principle says at least 2 people (objects) share the number of hairs(boxes).